How can I find the code used to create the color of the track of a SwitchMaterial used by default based on the colorSecondary set in the theme?
I want to use this color somewhere else in the app, but I don't know how they prosses the color of the thumb to create its track.
The color of the thumb is taken from colorSecondary in the theme. It's #FFCC80.
But How do they create the track color based on the thumb color?

Ok, I found a different solution, I can use layout inspector in Android Studio to see the trackTint color:  #D6BA91.

